# Unrecognized Selector SenTestCase for Category

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, testing

I created a new Cocoa Touch Static Library project with Unit Testing in XCode 4 and added a  category:

```
// NSString+Inflections.h
@interface NSString (Inflections)
- (NSString *)pluralize;
@end

// NSString+Inflections.m
@implementation NSString (Inflections)
- (NSString *)pluralize { return self; }
@end
```

then added the appropriate import statement to my test cases and wrote the following test:

```
- (void)testPluralize
{
  NSString *test = @"person";
  NSString *expected = @"people";

  NSString *actual = [test pluralize];

  STAssertEqualObjects(actual, expected, @"Whoops"); 
}
```

However, this causes my tests to crash (not fail) with 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'.

How can I test a category inside a library?

I've compressed and uploaded the full project [here](http://cl.ly/2I2Y261w2L3b07311T2R) if my description is inadequate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was searching for an answer this problem myself and found (I believe) a simpler solution, which doesn't require remembering to add a reference in the Compile Sources list whenever a new category class is added to the project.

In the test target's build settings, add `-ObjC` to the Linking / Other Linker Flags value.

Further explanation for why this error actually happens can be found at [Apple Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Sometimes I wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: @Shaggy Sorry I didn't change out the answer. I just ran into this problem again and this is a much better fix.

Comment: not work for me :( I have static library need to write unit test. Code compile and build successfully but test case fail unrecognized selector. It works fine when I add .m file in test target

Comment: When I am adding -ObjC lot of `Apple Mach -O` error comes

Answer (score 13):

**Edit: Be sure to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783294/link-error-while-building-a-unit-test-target/6624534#6624534) about unit test not finding files**

+1 For uploading the project. The problem is your test target does not include NSString+Inflections.m in the Build Phases.

In XCode 4

1. Click "Poppy" in the top of the Navigator
2. Select "PoppyTests" under Targets
3. Go to Build Phases
4. Expand Compile Sources
5. Click the + sign and then add NSString+Inflections.m

You should then get something similar the following output

> **TestSuite '/blahblah/PoppyTests.octest(Tests)' finished at 2011-03-28 21:31:34 +0000.
>   Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0
>   unexpected) in 0.000 (0.002) seconds**

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem, but PoppyTest target does have Poppy as a dependency. I did a bit more looking and found that it can also be fixed by adding `-all_load` as a Other Linker Flag for the PoppyTest target (under Build Settings). This way one wouldn't need to add all source files to both targets.

Comment: That is correct I did not see that, I was thinking it was an `-all_load` kind of issue at first because you were working with a category. I would recommend `-force_load [dependency name]` if it were not a unit test because that option will only load all symbols in the specified dependency.

Comment: This fixed it for me. The odd part was it was working fine and when it stopped working for me it was using the old source files.

Comment: @KevinSylvestre How do you set the -all_load flag? Is it somewhere in Build Settings?

Comment: Bill's answer below is much better than this one. You should not manually add your library's source files to the unit test target. Every time you do, a kitten cries. You should link your unit test against your library instead. Every time you do that, a kitten smiles.

Answer (score 1):

I can also confirm that adding the required files to the Test project's Build Phases > Compile Sources collection solves this problem. Thanks a bunch!

When I tried the -all_load approach, however, I started to receive a bunch of errors, like that _CGSizeZero is undefined for architecture i386. It turns out that some code - like this one, where I use CGSizeZero in one of my classes - can make the second approach break.

Once I replaced CGSizeZero with CGSizeMake(0, 0), however, the second approach worked great as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation when i was working in the Objective-c project. I did the following steps and it went well.

1) Select the project and goto target.

2) select Test target and add `-ObjC` like showing in the image.

[image]

3) Now try to run the unit XCTest.