# Unit testing app extensions iOS8 via framework

Tags: ios, unit-testing, frameworks, ios8-share-extension

[So referring to this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627600/how-to-unit-test-an-app-extension-on-xcode-6) it is recommended by apple to put all your code in a framework so you can test it.

So my questions are does this have to be an embedded framework or can you create a separate project and put all the extension code in there?

My concern is because upon creating an extension it comes with an info.plist file and an entitlements file and i am unsure where i should be putting those in relation to the framework and such.

Also once you have made the separate or embedded framework project, how do you set the host for your test? mine is mostly interested in the host app being photos, but saying that i need the actual storyboard to load that derives from `SLComposeServiceViewController`. So would you create an app delegate target that you can set as the host, and then have that load the `MainInterface.storyboard` of your extension to start the testing?

### Update

So I have recently discovered the difference between application testing and logic testing. So to update my question slightly, is there a way to application test your extension UI? my assumption would be to have an app host target and load the first view to be your extension storyboard view.

Comment: have you been able to figure out a testing strategy for your extension? I'm looking into the same thing atm.