# Media Attachment in iOS 10 Push Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10, ios-app-extension, unnotificationserviceextension

I'm struggling with adding an image to my Push Notification in iOS 10.

I have added a Notification Service Extension, and have used the following code:

```
        override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)


    if let urlString = request.content.userInfo["image-url"] as? String, let fileUrl = URL(string: urlString) {
        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: fileUrl) { (location, response, error) in
            if let location = location {
                let options = [UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsTypeHintKey: kUTTypePNG]
                if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: location, options: options) {
                    self.bestAttemptContent?.attachments = [attachment]
                }
            }
            self.contentHandler!(self.bestAttemptContent!)
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

I got this code from the first answer below.

The issue I'm having now is that the notification is received, with a short delay which indicates the download must be happening, but there is no attachment shown.

I am assuming that `serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire()` is being called and just showing the `bestAttempt`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have my APNs payload configured correctly, I believe:

```
apns: {
  aps: { 
    alert: { 
      title: "Title", 
      subtitle: "Subtitle", 
      body: "Body"
    }, 
    "mutable-content": 1
  },
  "image-url": "https://helloworld.com/image.png" 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to pull the url out of the notification's user info, then download the image and give a file url to the attachment. Try something like:

```
if let urlString = request.content.userInfo["image-url"] as? String, let fileUrl = URL(string: urlString) {
    URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: fileUrl) { (location, response, error) in
        if let location = location {
            let options = [UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsTypeHintKey: kUTTypePNG]
            if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: location, options: options) {
                self.bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
            }
        }

        self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent)
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to use my updated code for movies or gifs, only images. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work this out with the following code:

Swift:

```
if let PusherNotificationData = request.content.userInfo["data"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let urlString = PusherNotificationData["image-url"] as? String, let fileUrl = URL(string: urlString) {
                URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: fileUrl) { (location, response, error) in
                    if let location = location {
                        let options = [UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsTypeHintKey: kUTTypePNG]
                        if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: location, options: options) {
                            self.bestAttemptContent?.attachments = [attachment]
                        }
                    }

                    self.contentHandler!(self.bestAttemptContent!)
                    }.resume()
            }
        }
```

Node:

```
apns: {
    aps: { 
      alert: { 
        title: "title", 
        subtitle: "subtitle", 
        body: "body"
        }, 
        "mutable-content": 1,
        category: "test"
      },
    data: {
      "image-url": "www.helloworld.com/image.png"
    } 
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I cannot seem to add a Gif or a Video by changing the file type hint. Also, removing this option stop my image from being loaded. It should still infer the file type from the url, right?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (and a testable one) could be writing the image in a temporally location:

```
    // NotificationRequestHandler
    func getImageURL(from userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) throws -> URL {
        // parse the image URL and return it, otherwise throws and error
    }

    func temporaryWriteData(from url: URL) throws -> (String, URL) {
        let temporaryDirectoryUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
        let temporaryFileName = UUID().uuidString
        let temporaryFileUrl = temporaryDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent(temporaryFileName)

        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        try data.write(to: temporaryFileUrl, options: .atomic)
        return (temporaryFileName, temporaryFileUrl)
    }
```

and on `didReceive(_:withContentHandler:)`:

```
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    defer {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent ?? request.content)
    }

    do {
        let handler = NotificationRequestHandler()
        let imageUrl = try handler.getImageURL(from: request.content.userInfo)
        let (imageFileName, imageFileUrl) = try handler.temporaryWriteData(from: imageUrl)
        let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: imageFileName, url: imageFileUrl, options: [UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsTypeHintKey: "public.png"])
        bestAttemptContent?.attachments = [attachment]
    } catch {}
```

Also something very helpful to [debug extensions](https://tech.hbc.com/2017-07-07-ios-notifciation-service-extension-tips.html)
and [how to test extentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627600/how-to-unit-test-an-app-extension-on-xcode-6/58538353#58538353)