# How to receive iOS10 Remote UserNotification

Tags: ios, ios10, usernotifications

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert" : {
      "title": "Daily Sales",
      "body": "Bed"
    },
    "badge" : 1,
    "mutable-content": 1
  },
  "my-attachment" : "https://secure.img1.wfrcdn.com/lf/maxsquare/hash/36984/27677880/1/Wimbush-Panel-Bed-DBHC7470.jpg"
}
```

This is a remote push notification payload. When the device receive this, and received by `func didReceive(UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler: (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)`, will the "my-attachment" go into the `content.attachments` directly? if I add more customize data in the json file? what will happen?

Comment: It won't go directly in the attachments, it will be in the user info of the notification's content. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399154/media-attachment-in-ios-10-push-notifications

Answer (score 0):

You have to download your atachment in the `Notification Service Extension file`. You can create an `UNNotificationAttachment` object out of it and pass in the completionHandler of `func didReceiveNotificationRequest(request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)` method of UNNotificationServiceExtension subclass.