# Can i embed image or movie in iOS 10 push notification message

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I often read that iOS 10 supports this feature now and that their push notification payload is increased in size but never seen it implemented in any mobile app so far. So anybody knows if that is implemented in any app so far ?

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399154/media-attachment-in-ios-10-push-notifications

Answer (score 1):

Yes, totally. **Starting from iOS 10+** you can now send and receive push notifications with Media. Media means an URL to photo, video or etc.

Comment: I saw it implemented in twitter and other apps. The image is small more like an app icon. What i am looking for is to display an image with full width and height inside the notification center without opening the app.

Comment: @HoussamHamdan you need to declare a custom view of your notifications programmatically or via custom xib.

Comment: Please provide me with a link to an article describing how to do that.

Comment: @HoussamHamdan see this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38066583/7326568
And for example official documentation from OneSignal about attaching media URL's to your Push-Notifications
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk

I would recommend to use OneSignal as it is easy to install & use out of the box.

Comment: @Oner Thanks for your link, looks like they gonna work. I will give them a try.