# Accessing category methods in Objective-C from a subclass

Tags: objective-c, subclass, categories, superclass

I'm creating a framework and I want to add private methods to a superclass inside a category so they are not exposed.

As an example let's say I have a **public** class defined as:

```
@interface Animal : NSObject

- (void)makeNoise;

@end
```

And a **public** subclass like:

```
@interface Dog : Animal

- (void)makeNoise;

@end
```

Now I want to add **private** methods related to all `Animal` objects so I create a category like:

```
@interface Animal(PrivateMethods) 

- (void)privateSing;

@end
```

And the problem comes here. Isn't it possible from the subclass to access the superclass `PrivateMethods` category?

If I run the following code, I get a `unrecognized selector sent to instace` error:

```
#import "Animal+PrivateMethods.h"
@implementation Dog

- (void)description {
    // unrecognized selector sent to instace
    [self privateSing];
}

@end
```

Comment: Is the category .m file included in your target?

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently this is only an issue when running the unit tests. When I import my framework in a separate project and run it, all the private methods are executed without any problem.

Comment: Sounds like you may have essentially the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675256/ismemberofclass-returns-no-when-viewcontroller-is-instantiated-from-uistoryboard

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes I was able to resolve it finally. I used this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465076/unrecognized-selector-sentestcase-for-category which in the end is the same as you suggest. Apparently when you create a new category using XCode's 4.5.1 wizard, it's not added by default to the Tests compile sources phase. Thanks!